# Cannot ping in WiFi AP

Tags: networking, wifi, ethernet

I'm trying to set up an access point with my Pi 3 in order to capture and analyze traffic in a domestic network. I also have connected a Philips Hue bridge to the Raspberry via ehternet. The raspberry here simulates a standard wifi router.

At the moment, both my laptop and the bridge seem to be connected to the network (192.168.4.0/24) with IPs 192.168.4.16 and 192.168.4.12 respectively. I can ping the bridge from my raspberry, but I cannot ping my laptop which is connected via the wlan0 interface even though it has an IP assigned. I cannot ping my raspberry from my laptop either.

```
         ---------
        |         | -> NIC1              ------> WiFi AP (pi-ap) (192.168.4.0/24)
        |         |    (wlan0 - 192.168.4.1/24)
        | PI      |                                       ------------
        |         | -> NIC2              -------> NIC1   | HUE bridge | 
         ---------     (eth0 - 192.168.4.2/24)            ------------
                                                         (eth0 - 192.168.4.12/24)
```

This is my /etc/dhcpcd.conf:

```
interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.4.1/24

interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.4.2/24
```

net.ipv4.ip_forward is enabled in /etc/sysctl.conf

I have this in my /etc/dnsmasq.conf:

```
interface=wlan0
dhcp-range=192.168.4.10,192.168.4.20,255.255.255.0,24h

interface=eth0
dhcp-range 192.168.4.3,192.168.4.5,255.255.255.0,24h
```

And this is my /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=pi-ap
hw_mode=g
channel=7
wmm_enabled=0
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=raspberry123
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pariwise=CCMP
```

I updated my iptables with an ACCEPT ALL policy to ensure no traffic is being blocked:

```
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

How can't I ping between the raspberry and the laptop if it is connected to the network and has an IP assigned? Am I missing any configuration?

Edit:
I think it might be a routing issue.
If I run route -n in my raspberry the result is:

```
Destination    Gateway    Genmask        Flags Metric Ref Use    Iface
192.168.4.0    0.0.0.0    255.255.255.0  U     202    0   0      eth0
192.168.4.0    0.0.0.0    255.255.255.0  U     303    0   0      wlan0
```

Do I need to add or modify something to the routing table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using `systemd-networkd`, so I'm not so familiar with your configuration. But there are some general issues that should be mentioned. You have enabled `ip forwarding`. This is for `routing`. But all your interfaces are on the same subnet `192.168.4.0/24`, even `eth0` and `wlan0` on your raspi. This can only be done with `bridging`. So you have to decide in general what to do: bridging or routing.

For `routing` you have to reconfigure your network into at least two subnets, one subnet for `eth0` and one different subnet for `wlan0`. Look here for [Using the Raspberry Pi as a Router](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/82267/79866).

Simple `bridging` on OSI Layer 2 between ethernet and wifi does not work on a Raspberry Pi because lack of WDS (Wireless Distribution System) and limitations in `4addr`. You have to use workarounds for a [Raspberry Pi WiFi to Ethernet Bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/81518/79866).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I ended setting up a bridge br0 between eth0 and wlan0, giving it a static IP and setting up dhcp service through br0.

Comment: Interesting but I don't really understand it. On a bridge you don't need ip addresses to work. Maybe you have found another workaround? Can you test `sudo iw dev wlan0 set 4addr on` and then add `wlan0` to the bridge? Is there an error message?

Comment: I don't think the ip address is necessary here, I just assigned it so I can log into the raspi through ssh