# Automatically switch between WiFi and Ethernet with static IP

Tags: networking, wifi, ethernet

As per the documentation found [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/networking-lessons/rpi-static-ip-address/) I have setup my dhcpd.conf with the following:

```
interface eth0

static ip_address=192.168.4.102/24
static routers=192.168.4.1
static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8

interface wlan0

static ip_address=192.168.4.102/24
static routers=192.168.4.1
static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8
```

However after a reboot only the Wifi has the new static IP:

```
2: enxb827ebfa27e1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:fa:27:e1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.4.37/24 brd 192.168.4.255 scope global enxb827ebfa27e1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::8dd2:e6ac:d404:fb53/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:af:72:b4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.4.102/24 brd 192.168.4.255 scope global wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5837:7479:fa9d:288a/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I would have logically expected the Pi to:

- Give both adaptors the same static IP address
- Automatically switch between adaptors with a preference for Ethernet (and therefore only use one at a time)

How do I achieve this?

Comment: The solution you can you find on [ Raspberry Pi Networking - Switching between wired and wireless networks in Raspbian & Debian ](http://www.aoakley.com/articles/2013-07-31-raspberry-pi-networking.php) The author uses static ips in his tutorial, but should work also with dynamic ips. Interesting is the ‘allow-hotplug’ command in the interface definition

Comment: Amazing that such a simple question is downvoted by neckbeards

Answer (score 1):

As should be obvious from the listing **you do NOT have `eth0`**

It is difficult to say why you are using `Predictable Network Interface Names` (even though most distos use it) as the Foundation nobbled it (you do not say what OS you are using).

This is explained in [How to set up networking/WiFi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

No matter what you do **you CAN NOT assign the same IP address to 2 interfaces**

It is also difficult to understand what you mean by "Automatically switch between adaptors". You can assign different metrics to interfaces.  `route -n` will show the current metrics.

Comment: Ah good point. Well, I selected yes when it asked, that's the reason I'm using it. By switch I would like it to use the ethernet when it's connected and switch to Wifi when it's not. I'm using raspbian.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called `dynamic failover`: switch over to another connection if one is broken but use a primary interface if both available. You can use `bonding` to achieve this but I haven't seen a solution with default network setup of Raspbian. With a little effort you can switch over to `systemd-networkd` to do this.

Look at [Howto migrate from networking to systemd-networkd with dynamic failover](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/78788/79866).

Answer (score 0):

For the static part I know the answer (with a clean install)
The new noops-Debian uses a different eth0=name it's in your case enxb827ebfa27e1
check this with

```
ifconfig
```

Edit in `/etc/dhcpcd`
*(on top of the document)*

```
profile static_eth0
interface enxb827ebfa27e1
static ip_address=192.168.4.102/24
static routers=192.168.4.1
static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Edit in /etc/network/interfaces
(chance the line with eth0 in:)

```
iface enxb827eb9e9b69 inet manual
```

then

```
reboot
```