# Using usb wifi and onboard wifi simultaneously to connect to internet

Tags: wifi, usb, wireless, wireless-adapter

I have a raspberry at a very remote site where the wifi range is not that great. I am using a USB wifi with the antenna to connect to the wifi. Should I disable the onboard wifi in this case as I am using external USB wifi.?

Also, is it safe to keep both the interfaces enabled (USB wifi + onboard wifi) on static IP address connected to the same ssid.? Will they create any clash.? I was planning to keep both the interfaces enabled, just in case if one fails for some reason, another interface can keep the things going.?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter if both interfaces are activated when then build in isn't configured in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`. But to avoid possible confusion I would prefer to disable the build in wifi interface with putting this into the `/boot/config.txt`:

```
# Disable Pi3 onboard WiFi
dtoverlay=pi3-disable-wifi
```

To use two interfaces for failover it isn't done to give both an ip address. Wifi will not switch over automatically. You have to reboot. To avoid this you must use `bonding`. Here is a suggestion to use [dynamic failover](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/78788/79866).

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options, (1) Disable onboard WiFi or (2) Use networkmanager instead of ifupdown.

(1) is explained already as another answer by @Ingo

(2) You can install networkmanager using `apt install networkmanager`

You can follow https://askubuntu.com/questions/377687/how-do-i-connect-to-a-wifi-network-using-nmcli to connect to network.

You can follow https://askubuntu.com/questions/947965/how-to-trigger-network-manager-autoconnect to make networkmanager autoconnect.