# Configuring 2 wifi interfaces, one DHCP and the other ad-hoc, in Stretch

Tags: wifi

I have a number of Pis running jessie, with 2 wifi interfaces. One of the interfaces (wlan1) connects to the local DHCP server, and the other (wlan0) connects to a local ad-hoc network. In jessie this works fine.

I have a new Pi running stretch, and this configuration no longer works.

In /etc/network/interfaces I have

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.XXX ← insert static IP address here
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    wireless-channel 1
    wireless-essid OLSR
    wireless-mode ad-hoc
```

In stretch the /etc/network/interfaces file appears to be deprecated, in favour of dhcpcd.conf. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out a way, using dhcpcd.conf, to configure an ad-hoc interface.

How can I configure an ad-hoc interface in stretch, and still have another interface using DHCP?

Edit: The new PIs are PI 3 B. The previous PIs are also PI 3 B. The onboard WiFi is the ad-hoc interface and the dhcp interface uses an EDIMax N150 WiFi dongle.

Comment: I would say to `sudo systemctl disable dhcpcd.service`, reboot and use networking with `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work. The ad-doc interface got configured, but the dhcp interface would not connect to the network.

Comment: I tried again and did get this working. BUT, it doesn't work immediately after a reboot, and neither does the WiFi icon in the status bar.

The WiFi icon says "connection to dhcpcd lost".

If I do `dhcpcd <interfacename>` from the command line, it connects to the DHCP server and gets an IP address. After this I have the expected network connectivity, though the WiFi icon still says "connection to dhcpcd lost".

Comment: Another problem with the above is when I run `raspi-config` to try to setup a WiFi connection (option N2 Wi-fi), I get the error message `Could not communicate with wpa_supplicant`.

Answer (score 2):

I have decided to improve this answer in a more generic way so it may not answer this question exactly anymore. For a more up to date solution please look at
[How to setup an unprotected Ad Hoc (IBSS) Network and if possible with WPA encryption?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/94048/79866).

---

I have tried to implement this with *systemd-networkd* because it is consistent and straightforward and not a mix up of conflicting different network managers. I will give this answer as an alternative.

For reference I use a RPi3B+ with [Raspbian Stretch Lite 2018-06-27](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) from scratch. directory. We need untouched interfaces to configure them otherwise we may get error messages.-->

### Step 1: setup systemd-networkd

For detailed information look at [1]. Here only in short. Execute these commands:

```
rpi ~$ sudo -Es
rpi ~# mkdir -p /var/log/journal
rpi ~# systemd-tmpfiles --create --prefix /var/log/journal

rpi ~# systemctl mask networking.service
rpi ~# systemctl mask dhcpcd.service
rpi ~# sudo mv /etc/network/interfaces /etc/network/interfaces~
rpi ~# sed -i '1i resolvconf=NO' /etc/resolvconf.conf

rpi ~# systemctl enable systemd-networkd.service
rpi ~# systemctl enable systemd-resolved.service
rpi ~# ln -sf /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

Configure the interfaces and create this two files. Give it your own ip addresses:

```
rpi ~# cat > /etc/systemd/network/08-wlan0.network <<EOF
[Match]
Name=wlan0
[Network]
Address=192.168.1.2/24
EOF

rpi ~# cat > /etc/systemd/network/12-wlan1.network <<EOF
[Match]
Name=wlan1
[Network]
DHCP=ipv4
EOF
```

### Step 2: setup managed connection to the LAN for wlan1

Setup **wpa_supplicant** with this file and your settings (ssid, psk) and enable it:

```
rpi ~# cat > /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan1.conf <<EOF
country=DE
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="wlan@hoeft-online.de"
    psk="realyNotMyPassword"
}
EOF

rpi ~# chmod 600 /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan1.conf
rpi ~# systemctl disable wpa_supplicant.service
rpi ~# systemctl enable wpa_supplicant@wlan1.service
```

Reboot and check connection with upgrade. Reboot again if there are drivers updated:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt update
rpi ~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
```

### Step 3A: setup unprotected ad-hoc interface using systemd unit

Alternative you can use *wpa_supplicant* for this (see Step 3B). To configure the wifi into ad-hoc mode we only have to execute two commands (don't do that now):

```
iw wlan0 set type ibss
iw wlan0 ibss join RPiNet 2432 # <-frequency
```

I do this with a *systemd* unit so we can also stop the service. Create a new unit file with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo -Es
rpi ~# systemctl --force --full edit ad-hoc-interface@wlan0.service
```

In the editor insert these statements, save it and quit the editor:

```
[Unit]
Description=create unprotected ad-hoc interface
Requires=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device
After=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device
Wants=network.target
Before=network.target

[Service]
Environment="SSID=RPiNet" "FREQUENCY=2432"
#EnvironmentFile=/usr/local/etc/wifi-adhoc.conf
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/sbin/iw %I set type ibss
ExecStartPost=/sbin/iw %I ibss join $SSID $FREQUENCY
ExecStop=/sbin/iw dev %I ibss leave
ExecStopPost=/sbin/iw %I set type managed

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Enable the service:

```
rpi ~# systemctl enable ad-hoc-interface@wlan0.service
```

reboot.

Check with:

```
rpi ~$ iw dev
rpi ~$ iw dev wlan0 link
rpi ~$ ip addr
rpi ~$ iw dev wlan1 scan | grep -B8 -A3 "SSID: RPiNet"
```

You should be able to:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl stop ad-hoc-interface@wlan0.service
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl start ad-hoc-interface@wlan0.service
```

To change the *ssid* and *frequency* you can edit the unit file:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl --full edit ad-hoc-interface@wlan0.service
```

Alternative you can use a config file. Then use `EnvironmentFile=` instead of `Environment=` in the unit and create a config file like:

```
rpi ~# cat > /usr/local/etc/wifi-adhoc.conf <<EOF
SSID=RPiNet
FREQUENCY=2432
EOF
```

For mapping frequency to channel look at [List of WLAN channels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels). Btw. frequency 2432 is channel 5.

### Step 3B: setup unprotected ad-hoc interface using wpa_supplicant

Setup **wpa_supplicant** with this file and your settings (ssid, psk) and enable it:

```
rpi ~$ sudo -Es
rpi ~# cat > /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf <<EOF
country=DE
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

# use 'ap_scan=2' on all devices connected to the network
# this is unnecessary if you only want the network to be created when no other networks are available
ap_scan=2

network={
    ssid="RPiNet"
    frequency=2432
    mode=1
    key_mgmt=NONE
}
EOF

1pi ~# chmod 600 /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf
rpi ~# systemctl disable wpa_supplicant.service
rpi ~# systemctl enable wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
```

I have found that the *wpa_supplicant.service* uses driver `nl80211` by default. But it cannot handle ad-hoc mode (see developer section). We have to use driver `wext`. To modify the service we create a drop-in file:

```
rpi ~# systemctl edit wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
```

In the editor insert these statements, save it and quit the editor:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/sbin/wpa_supplicant -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-%I.conf -Dwext -i%I
```

reboot.

Check with:

```
rpi ~$ iw dev
rpi ~$ iw dev wlan0 link
rpi ~$ ip addr
rpi ~$ iw dev wlan1 scan | grep -B8 -A3 "SSID: RPiNet"
```

### For developers and for troubleshooting

I have tried to setup a secured ad-hoc wifi network using encryption with WPA/WPA2 without success. But this are some things I have done to find the answer. I do not want to discard them because it has taken some time and it may help me later and others on similar issues.

**manual setup**
For testing how it works you can execute these commands [2]. Be sure the interface isn't occupied by another service:

```
rpi ~$ sudo -Es
rpi ~# iw wlan0 set type ibss
rpi ~# ip link set wlan0 up
rpi ~# iw wlan0 ibss join RPiNet 2432
rpi ~# ip addr add 192.168.1.2 dev wlan0
rpi ~# ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.2
rpi ~# exit

rpi ~$ # check with:
rpi ~$ iw dev
rpi ~$ iw dev wlan0 link
rpi ~$ ip addr
rpi ~$ sudo iw dev wlan1 scan | grep -B8 -A3 "SSID: RPiNet"
```

You can do this also on a second raspi with another ip address, e.g. 192.168.1.3. Then you can ping it.

**unusable driver `nl80211`**
On testing with *wpa_supplicant* using ad-hoc mode I always get a strange initialization that looks like this:

```
rpi ~$ iw dev
phy#0
        Unnamed/non-netdev interface
                wdev 0x2
                addr 86:50:89:38:f2:93
                type P2P-device
                txpower 31.00 dBm
        Interface wlan0
                ifindex 3
                wdev 0x1
                addr b8:27:eb:06:e8:8b
                type managed
                channel 34 (5170 MHz), width: 20 MHz, center1: 5170 MHz
                txpower 31.00 dBm
```

When you get this `Unnamed/non-netdev interface` (type P2P-device) then you have a problem. It occupies the interface. When trying to `iw wlan0 set type ibss` I got the error messages:

```
Jul 07 22:06:17 wpa_supplicant[262]: nl80211: Failed to set interface into IBSS mode
Jul 07 22:06:17 wpa_supplicant[262]: wlan0: Association request to the driver failed
```

Looking with `systemctl cat wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service` you can see that *wpa_supplicant* is using first driver `nl80211` and then driver `wext`. This is given by parameter `-Dnl80211,wext`

```
rpi ~$ systemctl cat wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service | grep '^ExecStart='
ExecStart=/sbin/wpa_supplicant -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-%I.conf -Dnl80211,wext -i%I
```

I found using driver `wext` avoids this unnamed interface. So we have to use a drop-in file to change the parameter to `-Dwext`.

**setup wpa_supplicant with encryption**
Now I tried to establish safe ad-hoc connections with encryption but I run into serious trouble. I found it on arch linux [2] and on:

```
rpi ~$ zcat /usr/share/doc/wpa_supplicant/examples/wpa_supplicant.conf.gz | grep -A10 '^# IBSS/ad-hoc network with RSN'
```

Setup *wpa_supplicant* with this file and your settings (ssid, psk) and enable it:

```
rpi ~$ sudo -Es
rpi ~# cat > /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf <<EOF
country=DE
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

# use 'ap_scan=2' on all devices connected to the network
# this is unnecessary if you only want the network to be created when no other networks are available
ap_scan=2

network={
    ssid="RPiNet"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    proto=RSN
    psk="verySecretPassword"
    mode=1
    frequency=2432
    pairwise=CCMP
    group=CCMP
}
EOF

1pi ~# chmod 600 /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf
rpi ~# systemctl disable wpa_supplicant.service
rpi ~# systemctl enable wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
```

Create a drop-in file as shown unter *Step 3B* above.

For encryption we need random numbers and we can get error messages like:

```
wpa_supplicant[262]: random: Cannot read from /dev/random: Resource temporarily unavailable
wpa_supplicant[262]: random: Only 18/20 bytes of strong random data available from /dev/random
wpa_supplicant[262]: random: Not enough entropy pool available for secure operations
wpa_supplicant[262]: WPA: Not enough entropy in random pool to proceed - reject first 4-way handshake
```

Fortunately the Raspberry Pi has a hardware random generator but to use it we have to install a driver:

```
rpi ~# apt install rng-tools
```

reboot.

The problem here is that the interface *wlan0* is configured and up but `systemctl status wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service` gives me an error message:

```
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-FAILURE EAP authentication failed
```

I don't know why. I cannot ping another ad-hoc configured raspi. There is no connection established. It was also reported that there is a problem when there is another raspi in ad-hoc mode and tries to connect [5]. If anyone has an idea how to fix one of these issues please give me a comment under this answer.

**refefences:**
[1] [Howto migrate from networking to systemd-networkd with dynamic failover](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/78788/79866)
[2] [Ad-hoc networking](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ad-hoc_networking)
[3] [List of WLAN channels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels)
[4] [Raspberry Pi 2018-04-18 - Cannot put device into adhoc mode](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/990)
[5] [Kernel trace in brcmfmac wifi driver when joining ad-hoc network w/another brcmfmac device](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/1742)
[6] [Linux WiFi Ad-hoc mode](https://wiki.lm-technologies.com/linux-wifi-ad-hoc-mode/)

Answer (score 1):

I have this working now. Milliways had the right idea with his PPS, but it needed a little bit more. I tried putting my ad-hoc settings in `/etc/network/interfaces`, and left the DHCP interface to get configured automatically by dhcpcd, so that `/etc/network/interfaces` looked like:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.XXX ← insert static IP address here
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    wireless-channel 1
    wireless-essid OLSR
    wireless-mode ad-hoc
```

This resulted in the ad-hoc interface getting configured correctly but the DHCP interface not working. Checking the status of dhcpcd using `sudo systemctl status dhcpcd` revealed the following error message

```
Not running dhcpcd because /etc/network/interfaces
defines some interfaces that will use a
DHCP client or static address
```

This led me to this post: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=191678, which contains the following tidbit

```
when I move conflicting settings from /etc/network/interfaces into directory
/etc/network/interfaces.d/ ,dhcpcd can be started by systemd successfully. Now 
I use this method to avoid confliction.
```

### My Solution

I followed the above advice and removed all the additions I had made to `/etc/network/interfaces`, and then created a new file `/etc/network/interfaces.d/wlan1` which contains the following:

```
auto wlan1
iface wlan1 inet static
    address 192.168.1.XXX ← insert static IP address here
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    wireless-channel 1
    wireless-essid OLSR
    wireless-mode ad-hoc
```

And I also added this line to the end of `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`, to prevent dhcpcd from configuring wlan1:

```
denyinterfaces wlan1
```

After making these changes and rebooting, the interfaces were configured and connected to the networks as expected.

Comment: +1. Is this a simple unprotected ad-hoc connection or is there any encryption with password authorization?

Comment: It is unprotected for the time being.

Comment: I have found an issue with my solution. If I try to change WiFi networks using WiFi icon on the upper right menu bar, I get disconnected from the current network and it will not connect to the new one. No error message, it just won't connect to anything until I reboot.

Comment: Actually, this appears to be a problem in general. I backed out all my changes, and that problem still persists for the USB WiFi.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are setting up an Access Point or an Ad Hoc network.

You can setup `dhcpcd` to manage interfaces - see **Advanced dhcpcd Configuration** in 
[How to set up networking/WiFi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

I am not sure if you are setting up an Access Point or an Ad Hoc network, but the tutorial contains a link to a Foundation instruction to enable the Pi to act as an Access Point using `dhcpcd`.

PS You don't mention which Pi or the WiFi modules, but using **Predictable Network Interface Names** makes using multiple WiFi modules more predictable.

PPS You **CAN** use `/etc/network/interfaces` in conjunction with `dhcpcd` provided you tell `dhcpcd` **NOT** to manage the interface **AND** don't use `dhcp` in `/etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: I am setting up an ad-hoc network for research purposes. The ad-hoc interfaces are for the ad-doc network, and the dhcp interfaces allow me to monitor the performance of the each node.

The new PIs are PI 3 B+. The previous PIs are PI 3 B.

I tried your PPS suggestion. When I include the configuration of the ad-doc network in `/etc/network/interfaces`, the dhcp interface does not get properly configured.