# Automatically connect to wifi after reboot

Tags: wifi

I have [pocket wifi](https://www.my-webspot.com/blog/what-is-a-pocket-wifi/) which is a portable wifi router.

It has a SSID and Password.

I want my RPi3 B+(ubuntu server 16.04) connect to that pocket wifi automatically after reboot.

Should I make some script that start when RPi boot up ?

please give me some advice !

Comment: What OS? What Pi model? What is a "pocket wifi"? What is a "static SSID" (is there any other kind)?

Comment: You should include this information in all questions (preferably as tags). Other answers will assume Raspbian, but Ubuntu MATE uses Network Manager (which AFAIK does not use wpa_supplicant - or at least wpa_supplicant.conf). I am unsure about the server. You would be better to ask on a Ubuntu site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect connected wifi IP address](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/90753/detect-connected-wifi-ip-address)

Answer (score 1):

Edit the wpa_supplicant.conf file:

```
network={
    ssid="yourHiddenSSID"
    scan_ssid=1
    psk="Your_wifi_password"
}
```

See more in the [official documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md).

Comment: Why do you assume the SSID is hidden? Why do you leave out some essential bits (like the country code)? Why do you assume OP's distro uses wpa_supplicant?