# Raspberry Pi 3B+ Ad-Hoc WiFi issue

Tags: wifi, pi-3b+, dhcp

I can't seem to connect to my Pi 3b+'s ad-hoc network. I set it up using https://github.com/simondlevy/RPiAdHocWiFi
I have attempted with two windows 10 machines and an android phone. On Windows 10 the network adapter just restarts when you attempt to connect. I can't figure out a way to view what is going wrong. On android nothing at all happens, it just shows a half second of loading.

I ran apt update and upgrade prior to installing RPiAdHocWifi.

Answer (score 1):

You don't tell if you want a secured ad hoc communication with wpa/wpa2 encryption or if unsecured connections are enough for you. You should know that everyone on your street who is a bit familiar with the monitor mode of a wifi adapter can spy your unsecured network. It is known that secured ad hoc communication has some trouble and the scripts you linked don't specify if it is secured. I had a look at it. It is really very simple and overwrites brute force existing configurations in networking and service start up and it use simple unsecured ad hoc communication. It also installs a DHCP server on the device. If you do this on each of your ad hoc devices you have more than one DHCP server on the network. This is outside specification and cannot work. Issue #1 on that project just reports problems with DHCP without a reply from the author.

I started with simple unsecured ad hoc connections and tried to establish secured connections because it was told that *wpa_supplicant* is able to do it. I have made it more as a feasibility study and to avoid the problem with the DHCP server I used static ip addresses. You may consider to use a main station that is always on and provide ip addresses with one DHCP server to other ad hoc stations. Look at [Configuring 2 wifi interfaces, one DHCP and the other ad-hoc, in Stretch](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/85684/79866). You may find some ideas how to configure an ad hoc wifi network.