# Raspberry 3B+ Can it be connected the same time for WiFi and for Ad-Hoc wireless network

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, wifi, pi-3b+, internet

Sorry guys, I'm not a Linux guru at all. So the problem:

1. I have a general wifi in my office and there is Internet shared
   via this network
2. I have a raspberry 3b+ device
3. I could connect
   rpi to this WIFI network and login to rpi with ssh

However, I need a way to create and Ad-Hoc wifi network with rpi.

Question: If I connected to a Raspberry via AdHoc wifi network - could Raspberrry device still has access to Internet over WiFi?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configuring raspberry Pi as a gateway of an ad-hoc network](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100843/configuring-raspberry-pi-as-a-gateway-of-an-ad-hoc-network)

Answer (score 0):

You typically can’t run an ad-hoc and dedicated access point on the same WiFi interface, so you’ll need to add a second WiFi interface in addition to the built-in WiFi. There are some very inexpensive USB options on amazon, and the Raspberry Pi folks sell one. Make sure it says RPi compatible.

Then look up one of the many online tutorials for building a rpi wifi bridge, and substitute your 2nd WiFi adapter for the Ethernet one. Here’s one I picked just because it wasn’t too old: [Using a raspberry Pi as a Wireless Bridge](https://medium.com/@jgarijogarde/use-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wireless-bridge-adapter-bc65ea21cffd)