# Sharing VPN conection via WIFI hostpot

Tags: networking, wifi, ethernet, vpn, share

I would like to know if someone has ever done this before.

I want to share a wifi connection via raspberry pi connected to the internet via Ethernet cable. I would like the Pi to run through a VPN and provide a secured VPN IP address to the connected devices via WIFI. See below:

Internet Provider --> Raspberry pi (via eth) --> Share secured internet connection via Rasberry PI using openVPN --> Laptop conected to the VPN via Rasberry wifi connection.

Is this possible to achieve? If so, how can I achieve this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course it is possible to configure a Virtual Private Network with OpenVPN using a Raspberry Pi. There is no difference to any other computer. So you will find many examples and setups on the internet, mainly used [Installing OpenVPN Access Server on a Linux system](https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/installing-openvpn-access-server-on-a-linux-system/).

I have setup some VPN with a Raspberry Pi to simplify things for home use. You can find some examples at [Simple openVPN with static keys](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/98183/79866) and at [How To Create A Private Subnet Behind Raspberry Pi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/85897/79866) and closest to your use case [Raspberry pi as access point with vpn](https://superuser.com/a/1320566/879258).

You may also consider to use **Wireguard** instead of **OpenVPN** because it is full integrated and supported by **systemd**, the default service management on the Raspberry Pi OS: [How to bridge an access point with a remote network by Wireguard?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/106337/79866).

Answer (score 0):

I will share more details of what I am trying to achieve.

I am going to be working from outside of the country for a few days and I need to have an IP from the country I reside in order for my work computer to work correctly.

As 3-party software is disabled and I can't install any tool on my laptop, so my only option to get an IP range from the country where I reside is only via the router, but can't make changes to the router firmware/software either.

Again, as I explained above, I can connect my RPi to the router where I am going to be working via ETH port. Then, my plan is to somehow, use the Pi to establish a connection to my VPN server in my country of origin via an OVPN client file (obtain an IP address from there) and share this IP address with my work laptop via WIFI. Finally, my work laptop would have an IP address from the country I reside and will have connectivity to the internet via that remote IP.

I am not sure if any of the links you share would let me what I have in mind after a quick look, but I am really new to this. Thanks :)