# dhcpcd and ssh fail to start after changing hostname

Tags: raspbian, ssh, dhcp

I accidentally changed my hostname to an invalid one, containing ".". I managed to change the hostname back to a valid one but the dhcpcd and ssh service fail to start. If I ping my RPi from another computer I get "Destination host unreachable". Also, RPi seems to not be connected to the network. I already tried changing to different hostnames using raspi-config. Nothing worked so far.

I use an ethernet cable connected to the RPi with interace **eth0**. I have Raspbian installed on a Flash Drive.

[image: dhcpcd]

[image: ssh]

Comment: How did you change it?

Comment: I changed it in these 2 files /etc/hostname and /etc/hosts

Comment: On the RPi ... what is the output of `hostnamectl` ? ... also, your error messages include a "exec format error" ... this may indicate that, somehow, your RPi has a few x86 executables rather than ARM ... Are there any other changes, updates, modifications to the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, any PPAs added, any extra packages downloaded and installed ignoring as many errors as possible?

Comment: You can check if the `sshd` program matches the system configuration with these two commands: Check the libc architecture using `dpkg -l libc6`  .... and then ensure `sshd` is the correct one for that architecture using: `ldd /usr/sbin/sshd`

Comment: Add the output from `file /usr/sbin/sshd`.

Comment: @RubberStamp
`dpkg -l libc6` -> `Name: libc6:armhf     Architecture armhf`
`ldd /usr/sbin/sshd` -> `not a dynamic executable`
@goldilocks
`file /usr/sbin/sshd` : `data` and `/etc/apt/sources.list` has a `stretch-backports main`

Comment: Two last questions... **1** What is the output of `ls -l /usr/sbin/sshd`   .... **2** What is the output of `strings /usr/sbin/sshd |head -n 15` ... It seems pretty clear that somehow at least some of the critical system executables have either been damaged or replaced... I would recommend getting a new SD card and reinstalling Raspbian.  You should be able to retrieve any information that you may need from the current SD card once you have a working RPi... use a USB card reader to retrieve any user files.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest, after the modification of the host-name, to connect a keyboard and a screen (if possible) to your raspberry, do a apt-get --purge remove and then install sshd again. Check also /var/log/syslog for errors.
We don't have your rasp version, jessie or streetch... Check the package list to be sure to have the right repository for packages install (compatible with your distribution).

Comment: The problem in this case is, that `dhcpcd` is also broken and so you cannot connect for updates.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the update. It is important.

Please post text and not images. Just the important error message is stripped-down: `dhcpcd(377): ... Exec format error ???`. With lack of further information I guess *dhcpcd* has problems to read its configuration file `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` or maybe there is anywhere a cached malformed hostname. Please check if there are some unknown entries in *dhcpcd.conf*. You can look at the journal if there are some related errors shown with:

```
rpi ~$ journalctl --boot --unit=dhcpcd.service
```

You can also try to run `dhcpcd` from the command line with the debug flag `-d` set:

```
rpi ~$ sudo /usr/lib/dhcpcd5/dhcpcd -w -d
# or maybe
rpi ~$ sudo /sbin/dhcpcd -w -d
```

This should give you detailed output on the screen (stderr) what's going on.

**Update:**
As I have learned from the comment it is very likely that `/sbin/dhcpcd` and `/usr/sbin/sshd` are broken or have been replaced. I also see just now that the error message:

```
Exec format error
```

is given on **dhcpcd** AND on **sshd**. Following the answer from *@Valentin R.* is a good advice for both packages. You can also first try to reinstall them with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt --reinstall install dhcpcd5
rpi ~$ sudo apt --reinstall install openssh-server
```

But because *dhcpcd* is not working it may be a problem that your **eth0** interface has no ip address and you cannot connect to the Raspbian repository for update. You can temporary configure the interface. For example I use the local network 192.168.10.0/24 with ip address 192.168.10.60 for the RasPi and default gateway 192.168.10.1. The gateway is the ip address from your internet router. You have to use the ip addresses from your network and must use one for your RasPi that isn't used by another device.

```
rpi ~$ sudo ip addr add 192.168.10.60 dev eth0
rpi ~$ sudo ip route add default via 192.168.10.1 dev eth0 proto static
rpi ~$ sudo bash -c "echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 >> /etc/resolv.conf"
```

Couldn't test it, hope it works.

If you can't get it to run you can use `systemd-networkd`. It doesn't need *dhcpcd*. For detailed information look at [<sup>**(1)**</sup>](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/78788/79866). Here only in short. Execute these commands:

```
# disable classic networking
rpi ~$ sudo -Es
rpi ~# systemctl mask networking.service
rpi ~# systemctl mask dhcpcd.service
rpi ~# sudo mv /etc/network/interfaces /etc/network/interfaces~
rpi ~# sed -i '1i resolvconf=NO' /etc/resolvconf.conf

# enable systemd-networkd
rpi ~# systemctl enable systemd-networkd.service
rpi ~# systemctl enable systemd-resolved.service
rpi ~# ln -sf /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

Create this file:

```
rpi ~# cat /etc/systemd/network/04-eth0.network
    [Match]
    Name=eth0
    [Network]
    DHCP=yes
```

Reboot.
Now you should have a network connection as before.

**Reference:**
[1] [Howto migrate from networking to systemd-networkd with dynamic failover](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/78788/79866)

Comment: `Exec format error` is I am pretty sure exactly what it sounds like.  The binary has been replaced or become corrupted.

Comment: @goldilocks Ah..I understand now: the format of the Exec(utable) file is erroneous. OK, we will see with debug.

Comment: @Ingo trying to run `dhcpcd` gives me the same error: `cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

Comment: @David I have just updated my answer.

Comment: @Ingo `ip route add default via 192.168.10.1 dev eth0 proto static` gives me `RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable`

Comment: What is your network? Do you have 192.168.10.1? Do you use an ethernet cable with interface **eth0** or do you have a wireless connection with interface **wlan0**? Is it possible to reflash your SD Card?

Comment: I have used my IP, yes I use an ethernet cable. I have Raspbian installed on a Flash Drive. @Ingo

Comment: I would guess more of the fs may be damaged and there was a `fsck` at boot recently; check if there is anything in `/lost+found`.

Comment: `/lost+found` is empty

Comment: @David I have updated the answer with using `systemd-networkd`. You can try this.

Comment: @Ingo Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, I couldn't test your commands because my RPi is no longer booting. It gives me `Kernel panic -not syncing`. At this point I think I will just reinstall Raspbian.

Comment: @David Thank you for the feedback. Most people simply does not respond anymore and I wonder what happened.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `sudo raspi-config` to change the host name again.  Change it to an unwanted name and then change it to the wanted name.  Perhaps raspi-config will make all the needed changes.

Comment: I already tried raspi-config.