# 2 Wifi NIC's that each only connect to one (different from each other) network

Tags: networking, wifi, raspbian-stretch, wireless, wireless-adapter

## The Setup:

- Raspberry Pi 3 B (*Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)*) and boots to Command Line
- (internal Wifi NIC) [**wlan0**]
- additional external Wifi NIC [**wlan1**]

## What I want to achieve:

I Have two different wireless networks: One is always available (**a**), the other one not (**b**). I want to configure the networking in a way, that:

```
wlan0 -> a
wlan1 -> b
```

and the following happens but should not:

```
wlan0 -> a
wlan1 -> a
----or----
wlan0 -> b
wlan1 -> b
```

How do I avoid this?

## What have i done so far?

**Try1 (wpa_supplicant.conf & /etc/network/interfaces)**

```
pi@raspi:~ $ cat /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=DE

network={
        ssid="HomeNetwork"
        psk="############"
        id_str="home"
}

network={
        ssid="MobileNetwork"
        psk="############"
        id_str="mobile"
}
pi@raspi:~ $ cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

iface mobile inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

iface home inet dhcp
```

**Try2**

I've booted to Desktop and connected the interfaces to the according network and rebooted to Command Line...

Comment: why did you say nothing about what actually happens? ... you said nothing about any problem and you did not ask any questions

Comment: what happens is what i explained above at "what should not happen"

Comment: it is not clearly stated that it is what happens ... it only says that it is an undesirable condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like to use **systemd-networkd** you can create two instances of wpa_supplicant that each can be managed independent from the other. Here in short I would do it.

First switch over to **systemd-networkd**:
Just follow to [Use systemd-networkd for general networking](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/108593/79866). You can use section **"♦ Quick Step"**. Then come back here.

Now create a wpa_supplicant.conf file for each connection (examples):

```
rpi ~# cat > /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf <<EOF
ctrl_interface=DIR=/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
p2p_disabled=1
country=DE

network={
    ssid="HomeNetwork"
    psk="PasswordHomeNet"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
EOF

rpi ~# cat > /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan1.conf <<EOF
ctrl_interface=DIR=/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
p2p_disabled=1
country=DE

network={
    ssid="MobileNetwork"
    psk="PasswordMobileNet"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
EOF

rpi ~# chmod 600 /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf
rpi ~# chmod 600 /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan1.conf
rpi ~# systemctl disable wpa_supplicant.service

rpi ~# systemctl enable wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
rpi ~# systemctl enable wpa_supplicant@wlan1.service
rpi ~# rfkill unblock wlan
```

We have to bring up the interfaces with these two files:

```
rpi ~# cat > /etc/systemd/network/08-wlan0.network <<EOF
[Match]
Name=wlan0
[Network]
DHCP=yes
#Address=192.168.1.86/24
#Gateway=192.168.1.1
EOF

rpi ~# cat > /etc/systemd/network/10-wlan1.network <<EOF
[Match]
Name=wlan1
[Network]
DHCP=yes
EOF
```

Reboot.

As you can see you have now two independent services you can manage each on its own way. For example if you have special settings for the mobile network you can do it only for the `wpa_supplicant@wlan1.service` or maybe give one interface a static ip address and gateway instead of DHCP enabled in its `.network` file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I pretty naively followed your steps but did not succeed. (I think i might have done the switching to systemd-networkd wrong). However, i found [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/78787/howto-migrate-from-networking-to-systemd-networkd-with-dynamic-failover)  on here. It describes the process of switching to systemd-networkd in more detail. So I'm trying this when i have the time.

Comment: @KiliJenkins Sorry, I have missed to bring up the interfaces with its configuration files in `/etc/systemd/network/`. I have updated the answer at the and. Starting with a fresh flashed Raspbian Stretch Lite image it will work. I have tested it.

Answer (score 1):

**Use different wpa_supplicant files** in [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)
describes how to setup networking to use different wpa_supplicant files for each interface.

Your `etc/network/interfaces` should work (only because it causes `dhcpcd` to disable itself) and can be configured to use multiple wpa_supplicant files, however this uses old Debian networking, which is far less robust than `dhcpcd`

There is no guarantee which interface will be assigned to wlan0/wlan1 due to a race condition (although the onboard WiFi  will probably win). To be sure you should enable  **Predictable Network Interface Names** (this is used by most modern Linux OS).