# Issue with some devices not connecting to Raspberry Pi set up as AP

Tags: wifi, pi-4, access-point

I have set up my Raspberry Pi (Raspberry Pi 4) as an Access Point by following this article: **[Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point - the easy way](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/88214/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-an-access-point-the-easy-way)** and section: **Setting up an access point with a bridge**.

I change the config to use WPA2 Personal (only) and tested and it works but only for some devices which is strange. For the moment 2 out of 4 devices seem to be able to connect while the others are not able.

Working devices:

- iPad Pro (latest release)
- Macbook Pro (latest OSX release)

Not working:

- iPhone (latest iOS release)
- PC with Windows 10 Pro

When changing from WPA2 to WPA1 my iPhone is able to connect but gives a security warning/information.
Nevertheless using WPA1 cannot be the solution ;)

Checking the logs (syslog) I can see the device is connecting/disconnecting but no error.

*my wpa_supplicant config*

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=GB

network={
        ssid="AP SSID"
        psk="my pass"
        proto=RSN
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        pairwise=CCMP TKIP
        auth_alg=OPEN
        mode=2
        frequency=2462
}
```

Any suggestion or help is appreciated on this matter.

Comment: I will have a look at it but I do not have an iPhone so I cannot test this. Is there a big difference between an iPad Pro and an iPhone? I will look for a MS Windows 10 computer for testing. Just a moment please, will come back then.

Comment: I can confirm that Windows 10 does not connect with WPA2 only. I'm just looking at the debug output of wpa_supplicant.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that MS Windows 10 has a problem to connect to an access point established by wpa_supplicant (using `mode=2`) and  only accepting **WPA2 (RSN)** encryption. I haven't seen this before in my tutorial you have used, because I still use **WPA** encryption as fallback. And that works.

About IPhone I cannot say something because I don't have one.

I have looked at the debug output of wpa_supplicant and see that MS Windows 10 just does not response to the WPA 4-Way Handshake initiated by wpa_supplicant. Because MS Windows 10 can connect to my home WiFi internet hotspot using WPA2, I suspect that wpa_supplicant has a problem here. You may consider to file a bug report to the wpa_supplicant development.

You can also try to use **hostapd** instead of **wpa_supplicant**.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a broader insidious issue with `wpa_supplicant` (on Debian only?), and not limited to the Pi. After many, many hours of following misleading symptoms, I can confirm that with:

- wpa_supplicant 2.8 on Debian Buster with default config plus `mode=2`, `ssid` and `psk` set, and every permutation of `pairwise`, `group`, `auth_alg`, `frequency` that could reasonable be tested;
- a wl81xxMOD WiFi module and the mainline wl81xx/wlcore kernel drivers;
- `dnsmasq` providing DHCP.

The client experience is either:

- connect without issue:

  - Early 2013 MacBook Pro running macos 10.14.6 (Mojave)
  - iPhone SE running iOS 13.6
  - Old Toshiba laptop running Windows 7
- report "unable to connect" or periodically cycle from connected to disconnected every 2 to 6 seconds:

  - Late model desktop PC running Windows 10.
  - Ancient ASUS laptop running Windows 10.
  - 2020 iMac running macos 10.15.6 (Catalina)

Changing to either Open (`key_mgmt=NONE`) or disabling WPA2 (`proto=wpa`) causes all clients to connect without issue.

My theory, uncomfortable as it is, is:

*wpa_supplicant, by default, advertises WPA and WPA2 but does not provide a WPA2 Authenticator. Old clients just use WPA and never notice. Newer clients (including Mojave on a 2020 iMac) try WPA2, which does not complete so they drop the connection and mystery abounds.*

The resolution appears to be:

*`wpa_supplicant` must be configured with `proto=wpa` to disable WPA2, or `wpa_supplicant` must be replaced with something that provides an WPA2 Authenticator like `hostapd`.*

This is despite the `wpa_supplicant` [Change Log](https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/wpa_supplicant/ChangeLog) stating that way back in 2009-11-21 (v0.7.0), parts of `hostapd` functionality were linked in so that "AP mode functionality can be used for WPA2-Personal networks". On the other hand, the author's [web page](https://w1.fi/wpa_supplicant/devel/) does state that `wpa_supplicant` implements "a WPA Authenticator" while `hostapd` includes a "IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2 Authenticator".

I still do not understand why for those clients that take 6 seconds before disassociation, the WiFi connection appears to be completely useable. If it really is an authentication issue, that seems like a glaring security hole.

Full log of my investigation that led to this conclusion appears [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251736422?login=true&page=1).