# Raspberry Pi as Gateway and Router

Tags: networking, internet

My goal is to have wired internet on different devices using the tethering from a smartphone.
My idea is that a raspberry pi receives internet over USB tethering of a smartphone, and acts than as a router for the Intranet, providing internet over a switch to different devices. Is this achievable, and if yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

When using USB tethering with your smartphone you should get a network interface when connected. Check with `ip -br addr`. I don't know what its name is on your installation but with the Raspberry Pi OS it is mostly named **usb0**. Now you have two interfaces: **eth0** connected to your switch and **usb0** (or however it is named) as uplink to your smartphone.

You can just enable ip forwarding between interfaces and set a NAT (network address translation) to have a simple working router. [Use a Raspberry Pi as router for a tethered internet connection](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/99005/79866). In that example just replace the modem and its interface with your smartphone. From the networking view it is just the same.

Comment: Thanks for your help, that works. Is it also possible to share the tethering to both eth0 and wlan0? I've got some trouble setting up /etc/network/interfaces such that both eth0 and wlan0 are in the same subnet..

Comment: @Trashin Yes, it is possible to bridge **eth0** and **wlan0** and connect with both to the internet. You should create a new question about this. Using`/etc/network/interfaces` on Raspberry Pi OS is deprecated. You should not use it anymore. You should [merge your both accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) 'Trashina` and Trashin` and then accept the answer. Only accepting an answer will finish the question and it will not pop up again and again for years and annoing us.