# Raspbian Buster - Keep network interface down on boot

Tags: wifi, systemd, pi-4, raspbian-buster

I am configuring my raspberry pi zero w for a project in which I am using a micro-USB Ethernet (eth0) and WiFi (wlan0) as network interfaces. I am using wpa_supplicant to configure wlan0 to connect to a wireless access point.  For my specific application, it is **critical** that wlan0 is kept down on boot and does not make any connection with networks specified in wpa_supplicant.conf until a user connects and interacts through the console. (Running something like ifconfig wlan0 up to bring the interface online and then running wpa_supplicant to load the configuration file manually.) It is not sufficient to erase/rename wpa_supplicant.conf on shutdown as this must configuration must be able to withstand random reboots / power-cycling.

Things I have tried:

- I found that wpa_supplicant was a child process of systemd by default, so I tried modifying dhcpd to stop wpa_supplicant from starting on boot
- tried writing a systemd service to bring the interface down on boot (ifconfig down), but I am too inexperience with systemd to configure this correctly
- tried editing /etc/default/networking and adding the line EXCLUDE_INTERFACE=wlan0 to no effect (although this did strangely seem to delay the boot process)

Any ideas how I should go about configuring my pi in this manner? The ultimate goal is to ensure no outside wireless observer can see the pi until someone manually makes a wireless connection.

Comment: Do you really need to keep the interface down (and why?) or do you want to prevent it from associating with a WiFi network?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There a different ways you could achieve what you want.

**Method 1 – use systemd-networkd**

If you want to use `systemd` just follow **step 1** and **step 3** of [this tutorial](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/78787/howto-migrate-from-networking-to-systemd-networkd-with-dynamic-failover). Just omit this command `systemctl enable wpa_supplicant@wlan0`, so `wpa_supplicant` won't bring your interface up at boot. If you want to start it manually run `sudo systemctl start wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service.`

**Method 2 – use dhcpcd**

The default way to manage network interfaces in raspbian is `dhcpcd`. I did not use this for a long time, but I guess if you add `denyinterfaces wlan0` to `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` it won't bring up your interface either.

Then you can start it manually by running, but you have to make a config file without `denyinterfaces wlan0`:

```
wpa_supplicant -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -Dnl80211,wext -iwlan0
dhcpcd -f /etc/dhcpcd-wlan0.conf wlan0
```

**Method 3 – disable dhcpcd**

If wlan0 is the only interface you use, you could also disable `dhcpcd.service` and just run it when it's needed.
To disable it run `sudo systemctl disable dhcpcd.service`.
Then you can manually start it with `sudo systemctl start dhcpcd.service`.

Comment: I have tried to the dhcpd method but when I try to bring up wlan0 later and run wpa_supplicant to load my wpa_supplicant.conf, wlan0 doesn't seem to connect to the network.  I'm not sure if this is because wlan0 isn't making a DHCP request or what is going on exactly.  If you have any other tips / resources I could look into for using dhcpd to do this, I would much prefer it over bootstrapping systemd to manage my network interfaces as shown in the provided tutorial.  thanks for the tips!

Comment: @randomdude887 You just use one interface, right? So you could also disable `dhcpcd.service` and just start it when needed.

Comment: I need my ethernet interface (eth0) to be online from boot and getting DHCP lease so I can ssh into it from the network that interface is connected to, so i don't think disabling dhcpd.service will help me much here

Comment: @randomdude887 So try to run `dhcpcd wlan0` after having started wpa_supplicant.

Comment: @randomdude887 and let me know if it works.

Comment: denyinterfaces works to keep the interface down and I am able to successfully re-enable it and connect wlan0 to an AP when desired, but dhcpcd wlan0 isn't getting me a DHCP lease.  Ideas?

Comment: @randomdude887 run `dhcpcd -d wlan0`. And look for error messages.

Comment: seems issue resolved itself (?) still trying to figure out why running dhcpcd wlan0 works now.  will keep you posted.  much thanks again

Comment: @randomdude887 updated the answer. You need another config file for wlan0.