# Cannot set static IP address for Wi-Fi

Tags: raspbian, wifi, pi-3b+, static-ip, raspbian-buster

I am trying to make static IP address on RPI 3B+ for both ethernet and Wi-Fi.

I was following this answer([How do I set up networking/WiFi/static IP address?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address)), but still could not do it.

So far I managed to do it for ethernet, but I cannot do it for wlan0(Wi-Fi).

Moreover, when I type `ifconfig`, I see only `eth0` and `lo`, not `wlan0`.

I am using Rasbpian Buster.

When I type ip link, I get following message:

```
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:9a:0a:e1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff `
```

**Part of /etc/dhcpcd.conf**

```
# STATIC IP CONFIGURATION - ETHERNET
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.88.10/24
static routers=192.168.88.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.88.1

# STATIC IP CONFIGURATION - WLAN
interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.88.200/24
static routers=192.168.88.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.88.1
```

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.88.10
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.88.1

auto wlan0
        wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.88.200
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.88.1
```

**/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf**

```
country=HR
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="SSID_NAME"
    psk="PASSWORD"
}
```

Can somebody tell me where is the problem?

Comment: Use the command `ip link` to see whether `wlan0` exists. Or `ifconfig -a` if you prefer the legacy command.

Comment: You should add the information to the question. So the driver for `wlan0` is loaded, but it hasn't been brought up. You could try to bring it up manually with `ifup wlan0`. If it doesn't work, look at the system logs.

Comment: I changed it.

When I type `ıfup wlan0`, I get following message.

ifup: /etc/network/interfaces:10: misplaced option
ifup: couldn't read interfaces file "/etc/network/interfaces"

Comment: Line 10 is the line with `wpa-conf`. `man interfaces` doesn't mention a `wpa-conf` keyword.

Comment: Can you tell me how should that line look like exactly?

Comment: Take the stuff out of /etc/network/interfaces. Do everything in /etc/dhcpcd.conf **ONLY**.

Comment: @Dougie why is that?

Comment: Because it simply doesn't work the way you've done it. You'll end up with two addresses assigned to one interface.

Comment: Is there any reason you ignored the warning in `/etc/network/interfaces`?
**# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'**
If you really must use static IP do it properly see [How to set up Static IP Address](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/74428/8697)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set up networking/WiFi/static IP address?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address)

Comment: @Milliways I was following that tutorial, but unfortunately failed to make it.

Comment: You can't have followed the tutorial, which has instruction for **EITHER** `dhcpcd` or Debian networking; Indeed it states **Then follow ONE of the following methods.** You have a strange combination of both, but have not followed the instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some things mixed up or unclear why do you use unfamiliar setups. Please note that old style Debian **ifupdown** networking (with `/etc/network/interfaces`) is deprecated at least since Raspbian Stretch and you should avoid using it. That may conflict with default used **dhcpcd**. You find a note in `/etc/network/interfaces` saying:

```
# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'
```

But you set static ip addresses with **dhcpcd** and with `/etc/network/interfaces`. What setup should be used? That cannot work. Please restore `/etc/network/interfaces` to its default setting and don't touch it again.

The settings in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` look good so far. Unclear is why you use two interfaces **eth0** and **wlan0** on the same subnet 192.168.88.0/24 with ip addresses 192.168.88.10 and 192.168.88.200. The kernel can only use one interface at a time to connect to the subnet. Having two interfaces on one subnet makes only sense if you want to have a failover interface if one fails.  But it doesn't help much because on a failed interface all stateful TCP connections will stuck when the kernel switches to the other interface. If you want failover then you have to use another strategy with bonding. Here is an example [Howto migrate from networking to systemd-networkd with dynamic failover](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/78788/79866).

With the available information I suggest just to set a static ip address in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` only for your favorite interface as you already have done and delete the entry for the other interface.

Comment: @JakovKusić You should not set anything in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: I tested it now and you are right, nothing should be in `/etc/network/interfaces`

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Debian HowTo](https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse#WPA-PSK_and_WPA2-PSK), the interfaces file should look like this:

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
        wpa-ssid myssid
        wpa-psk ccb290fd4fe6b22935cbae31449e050edd02ad44627b16ce0151668f5f53c01b
```

For static addresses you have to adapt the address configuration, but the wireless part is the same.

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
        wpa-ssid myssid
        wpa-psk ccb290fd4fe6b22935cbae31449e050edd02ad44627b16ce0151668f5f53c01b
        address 192.168.88.200
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.88.1
```

Comment: It is written `iface wlan0 inet dhcp`, can `dhcp` be used for static IP?

Comment: For static you have to add the information, I added the addresses from your example.

Comment: The "Debian HowTo" **DOES NOT** cover `dhcpcd` - the default Raspbian network manager. The OP's problem is caused by attempting to use both (incompatible) methods.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of Ubuntu and Debian, netplan is used.  You need to add something similar to below in a file in /etc/netplan/ and have a file extension of .yaml.  You can just add to the default file in /etc/netplan/:

```
wifis:
        wlan0:
             dhcp4: false
             addresses:
                     - 192.168.10.9/24
             routes:
                     - to: 0.0.0.0/0
                       via: 192.168.10.2
                       metric: 600
                     - to: 192.168.10.0/24
                       via: 0.0.0.0
                       metric: 600
             access-points:
                     "SSID goes here":
                        auth:
                           key-management: psk
                           password: "passwordhere"
```

Comment: Jakov has already told us he's using Raspbian Buster, so your answer is off-topic.

Comment: Are you suggesting netplan can be used in Raspbian?

Comment: Raspbian Buster is based on the latest Debian, I believe the latest Debian (I know the latest Ubuntu has) switched to using netplan as the default, and if you do not want it you have to change the config.