# Interface gateway IP gets auto-configured after some time after deletion

Tags: wifi, raspbian-stretch, ethernet

I'm writing a script to control my network interfaces. I've three network interfaces viz `eth0`, `ppp0`, `wlan0`. I want such a configuration that when there is no internet available on `eth0`, it should switch to `ppp0` and when `ppp0` is also down, it should switch to `wlan0`.

Whenever I need to switch from `eth0` to `ppp0`, I write following command:

`sudo route add default gw "IP of ppp0"`

And it gets connected. But the problem is there while switching between `eth0` to `wlan0` and vice-versa.

Sometimes while using `sudo route add default gw 192.168.1.254 eth0`, I get following response:

```
SIOCADDRT: File exists
```

And interface do not switch.

I check for the `route` command and I got following result:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
default         192.168.43.141  0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlan0
10.64.64.64     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    304    0        0 ppp0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
192.168.43.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0
```

Then I've to remove all interfaces by using following command multiple times:

```
sudo route del default
```

Then after checking `route` again, I successfully deleted existing gateways and get this:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.64.64.64     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    304    0        0 ppp0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
192.168.43.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0
```

But the problem I faced is that, after 4-5 minutes, these gateways appears again without any changes made by me. Help me to make me understand the working of linux here. How gateway IPs are configured automatically and how can I prevent it to do so.

Comment: What you are (probably) trying is an exercise in futility - although you haven't said what you are doing.
`/etc/resolv.conf` contains `# Generated by resolvconf` - this is normal for virtually all dhcp clients. You can change it but it will be overwritten! 
What you (probably) want can be done with `dhcpcd` - see [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)
NOTE having 2 default routes is a recipe for disaster!

Comment: One of my question is, after deleting the gateway, how they're configuring again after few minutes?

Comment: because it is  automatically **Generated by resolvconf**

Comment: Ok. I'll try what you told.

Comment: You should not reinvent the wheel. What you try is a typical dynamic failover and that is managed with **bonding**. You can find an example with two interfaces at [Howto migrate from networking to systemd-networkd with dynamic failover](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/78788/79866). But it is no problem to have more interfaces with **bonding**.